# Can you create a new character using your previous character's weapons?

Tags: borderlands-2

After completing Borderlands 2, I want to start a new game with a new character using the weapons of my previous character. Is there any way I can do this?

Comment: Related http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/110029/can-i-start-a-new-game-in-borderlands-2-but-use-an-old-character

Comment: @Blim nope, not really... That one's about quests and keeping the character, this one's about guns and a new character.

Answer (score 3):

Use the shared stash. You can add upto 4 items to your shared stash, and any other creatures you create can access these items. You can also upgrade it.

It is located in Sanctuary, in the northwest.

Video example from ign - [shared stash](http://uk.ign.com/videos/2012/09/17/borderlands-2-walkthrough-claptraps-secret-stash-side-missions-part-7)

Comment: To access it with the second character you first need to complete the mission Claptrap's Secret Stash, when you first get to Sanctuary.

Comment: To be more precise, the stash is a locker located near Claptrap in Sanctuary.

Comment: Worth noting that unless you kept your old guns, your new character won't be able to use them until they meet the level requirement.